# Django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where should the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable be set?

Multiple possible locations:

- In a config file (`.ebextensions`) as follows:

  option_settings:   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "app.settings"
- In the `wsgi.py` file before application is loaded
- In `manage.py` (I also see this on different Django projects on the web)

If I don't specify it in `wsgi.py`, it looks like it can't be found at all. Therefore, I wonder if the environment variables set in `.ebextensions` are set before `wsgi.py` is loaded.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce your `wsgi.py` in a config file in `.ebextensions`

django_aws_eb.config:

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: "my_site/wsgi.py"
```

Specifly your DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE in your `wsgi.py' file

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_site.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

aws beanstalk first looks for configs in .ebextension to then locate wsgi.py to then locate settings.

more info: [Configure Your Django Application for Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb)